# Javascript: Split into multiple variables

Tags: javascript, python, variables, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to assign to multiple variables from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/907042/possible-to-assign-to-multiple-variables-from-an-array)

If in python i can do this

```
x = "Hi there and hello there"
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5 = x.split(" ")
```

but im not sure how to do it in javascript..

Comment: In short: there is no equivalent. I'm coming from Ruby and we've also been spoiled by these kinds of features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn it into an array by using javascript `.split`

For example

```
x = "Hi there and hello there";
var array = x.split(" ");
```

Then all your variables will be in the array like below

```
array[0]
array[1]
array[2]
```

You can show this using console.log or an alert like so.

```
console.log(array[0]);
alert(array[0]);
```

**References**

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-split.php

Answer (score 5):

What you are asking is called "destructuring assignment" which is a feature of Javascript 1.7. Sadly, not all browsers support these JS 1.7 features (Chrome for example, executes code marked as JS 1.7 but does not yet support this feature).

Your code will work on Firefox (as long as you mark it as JS 1.7 and with a slight modification) but not on Chrome.

To see this in action, use the following **with Firefox**:

```
<script type="application/javascript;version=1.7"/>
    x = "Hi there and hello there"
    var [v1, v2, v3, v4, v5] = x.split(" ")
</script>
```

Comment: This is neat and the way I was expecting splits to be done. (Having been using perl for a long time, I like this simple approach). Sadly firefox is the only thing that supports :(

Comment: omg this works in Google Apps Script! You can even leave out the ones you don't need like this `var [, component, method] = arguments.callee.name.split('_');`

Answer (score 1):

`split` splits the string into an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

Split returns an array.

```
var x = "Hi there and hello there"
var v = x.split(" ")
console.log(v[0]);
console.log(v[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can attach the variables to an object, then you could do it this way:

```
var stringToWords = function (str) {
if (typeof str === "string") {
    var stringsArray = str.split(" "),
        stringsSet = {};

    for (var i = 0, wordsNumber = stringsArray.length; i < wordsNumber; i++) {
        stringsSet['str' + (i + 1)] = stringsArray[i];
    }

    return stringsSet;
} else { 
    return str + " is not a string!!!"}
```

};

// this will return an object with required strings

```
var allStringWords = stringToWords("Hi there and hello there");
```

//then you can access a word this way:

```
allStringWords.str1
```

but I'm sure there are shorter ways to gain the same