# Most efficient way to extract parts of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I have a bunch of strings in the format 'TYPE_1_VARIABLE_NAME'.

The goal is to get 3 variables in the form of:

```
varType = 'TYPE',
varNumber = '1',
varName = 'VARIABLE_NAME'
```

What's the most efficient way of achieving this?

I know I can use:

```
var firstUnderscore = str.indexOf('_')
varType = str.slice(0, firstUnderscore))
varNumber = str.slice(firstUnderscore+1,firstUnderscore+2)
varName = str.slice(firstUnderscore+3)
```

but this feels like a poor way of doing it.  Is there a better way? RegEx?

Or should I just rename the variable to 'TYPE_1_variableName' and do a:

```
varArray = str.split('_')
```

and then get them with:

```
varType = varArray[0],
varNumber = varArray[1],
varName = varArray[2]
```

Any help appreciated. jQuery also ok.

Comment: what do you mean by "better", or "most efficient"?What exactly would make option A "better" than option B or C? Most efficient for what? code execution? code maintainability? readability?

Comment: Regular expressions

Comment: I'd recommend the `var arr = str.split('_')` method of doing it

Comment: `(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)$`, your groups will have your values. Or `(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*)`

Comment: I guess I mean least amount of code that isn't comparatively much slower.  A regEx here feels unnecessary, no?

Comment: i wouldn't worry about speed too much in this case (unless you're looping over tens of thousands of these,) so pick whichever is most readable to you.

Comment: How many choice you have because you already said regex no :) Anyhow, split is the best way!

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907042/possible-to-assign-to-multiple-variables-from-an-array

Answer (score 2):

### Regex solution

Given that the first and second underscores are the delimiters, this regex approach will extract the parts (allowing underscores in the last part):

```
//input data
var string = 'TYPE_1_VARIABLE_NAME';

//extract parts using .match()
var parts = string.match(/([^_]+)_([^_]+)_([^$]+)/);

//indexes 1 through 3 contains the parts
var varType = parts[1];
var varNumber = parts[2];
var varName = parts[3];
```

Given that the first variable consists of characters and the second of digits, this more specific regex could be used instead:

```
var parts = string.match(/(\w+)_(\d)_(.+)/);
```

### Non-regex solution

Using `.split('_')`, you could do this:

```
//input data
var string = 'TYPE_1_VARIABLE_NAME';

//extract parts using .split()
var parts = string.split('_');

//indexes 0 and 1 contain the first parts
//the rest of the parts array contains the last part
var varType = parts[0];
var varNumber = parts[1];
var varName = parts.slice(2).join('_');
```

In matters of efficiency, both approaches contain about the same amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex and `split`

```js
var string='TYPE_1_VARIABLE_NAME';

var div=string.split(/^([A-Z]+)_(\d+)_(\w+)$/);

console.log('type:'+div[1]);
console.log('num:'+div[2]);
console.log('name:'+div[3]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522406/javascript-split-string-straight-to-variables):

```
var array = str.split('_'),
    type = array[0], number = array[1], name = array[2];
```

ES6 standardises destructuring assignment, which allows you to do what Firefox has supported for quite a while now:

```
var [type, number, name] = str.split('_');
```

You can check browser support using Kangax's [compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#destructuring).

Here's a sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35zrm0sq/1/)